# How to find a specific name without "WHERE" in an Oracle schema?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my screenshot for my homework, which uses the Oracle sample Human Resources schema:

[HERE IN THE SCREENSHOT](https://www.onenote.com/webapp/pages?token=IDTJg9a7fkW0hsN4FkjwQ_YZBd2onXGmcZAGdHB-Jw2oG4YWTUAUyRoYhpR5oPRdgsDcRsEx5YyNn4Nf2luIwbJ4ChLiNwW00&id=636211352371940686)

So, my result list is the same as on the link above. But the query used is not acceptable in my homework. Since the assignment says:

> "you cannot use either 'WHERE E.DEPARTMENT_ID=D.DEPARTMENT_ID' or any
>   'JOIN' statement in the query string."

I am using Oracle Database 10g Express Edition.

Do you have any idea what my teacher wanted me to consider?

Here is my code:

```
SELECT   D.DEPARTMENT_NAME AS depName, LAST_NAME || ', ' || FIRST_NAME AS empName 
  FROM   DEPARTMENTS D, EMPLOYEES E 
  WHERE  E.DEPARTMENT_ID=D.DEPARTMENT_ID 
UNION ALL 
SELECT   '!w/o department!' AS reszleg, FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME AS empName 
  FROM   EMPLOYEES E 
  WHERE  DEPARTMENT_ID IS NULL 
ORDER BY depName, empName
```

Comment: Please paste your query into the question rather than linking a screenshot.

Comment: What are the inputs, and what are the requirements? In this world of hacking, don't ask us to follow links to who-knows-what websites; and express your requirement in common language, rather than code.

Comment: You can't use `JOIN` nor can you use `WHERE` but you are required to list the Department Name with the Employee name? Perhaps then it will allow a correlated subquery in the SELECT portion of the first statement? `SELECT (SELECT department_name FROM department WHERE department_id = e.department_id), employee_name FROM Employee UNION ALL`

Comment: Can you use `WHERE` just not that specific `WHERE` clause?

Comment: That link is for my Microsoft account (onenote.com) and not some malicious link.

But, OK, here is one query that gives the exact result I want to see:

SELECT D.DEPARTMENT_NAME AS depName, LAST_NAME || ', ' || FIRST_NAME AS empName
FROM DEPARTMENTS D, EMPLOYEES E
WHERE E.DEPARTMENT_ID=D.DEPARTMENT_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT '!w/o department!' AS reszleg, FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME AS empName
FROM EMPLOYEES E
WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID IS NULL
ORDER BY depName, empName

Even though it results in the desired table, it is not acceptable because of the use of the "WHERE E.DEP....." line

Comment: Just for the record, that is a stupid assignment as the best way to get such information is by using a join. However, Likely a correlated subquery woudl do the trick. Of course in production environments, I take out correlated subqueries as they are performance killers, but your teacher likely wants you to learn them for some inexplicable reason.

Comment: The specific WHERE clause I am not allowed to use is,
"WHERE E.DEPARTMENT_ID=D.DEPARTMENT_ID"

Comment: Also since you are learning,,never use an implict join; They are a very bad form of SQL coding and a SQL antipattern and have been replaced for more than 20 years. Always use explicit joins.

Comment: @HLGEM
What would such a correlated subquery look like? (or at least, what statements should be used?)
The teacher is tricky indeed, he asked for four different ways to reach the same result-set.

Comment: Please edit your post and add the query (use 4 space indentation to trigger code formatting).The comment is not the rigtht place.

Comment: Please add the code as formatted text. For me the link is not working at all.

Comment: @ZoliBee, see Jnevill's comment.

Comment: OK... it seems the "input data" is from the standard HR schema? You still didn't provide the other thing I said is necessary: a statement of your requirement, IN COMMON LANGUAGE. What do you want us to do, read your query and reverse-engineer the requirement? Why? What is the query supposed to achieve?

Comment: To clarify my question: What do you mean by "find Kimberely Grant"? What is special about her? Do you just need to find the employee with `null` for department_id? If so, why do you need the `departments` table at all?

Comment: @mathguy: please do not annotate your edits with your name. That information is captured in the edit history.

Comment: @halfer - is that the policy on the site? I wasn't aware, I will keep that in mind and I will see if I can find the few other edits where I did the same.

Comment: @mathguy: you are the only high-rep user that I've seen doing it, so by consensus it has become policy, as far as I know. If you are in any doubt about it, please ask a Meta-question.

Comment: @HLGEM: The query in JNevill's comment doesn't work. :(

Comment: @mathguy: I have clarified everything:) The query in opening post gives the very result the teacher wants to see--what he doesn't want to see is the line "WHERE E.DEPARTMENT_ID=D.DEPARTMENT_ID" or a "JOIN"

Comment: "Thanks" for  editing the original question. What we can see now is leading ppl astray, a new question, not the one I was interested in. BTW, what I was trying to ask was clear from the query string and screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you have any idea what my teacher wanted me to consider?

I guess that the teacher want to know if you have learned the `HAVING` clause.
The `HAVING` clause is usually associated with `GROUP BY` clause, but it also can be used without `GROUP BY`, and in this case it works in the same way as ordinary `WHERE` clause.
Please examine this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcb16/60277

```
SELECT *
FROM ForgeRock
WHERE id = 2;

SELECT *
FROM ForgeRock
HAVING id = 2;
```

Both queries give the same result.